# How can I inject arguments into a routee of akka RoundRobinPool with guice

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, akka, guice

I'm using Play Framework, Akka and Guice. The need is to simply inject some service (or another actor) into an actor which is created by a router which is injected into some controller.

I have a router config:

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /job-router {
    router = "round-robin-pool"
    nr-of-instances = 10
  }
}
```

And a module to bind this router

```
class ComponentModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {

  def configure() ={
    bindActor[JobActor]("job-router",(p: Props) => FromConfig.props(JobActor.props))
  }
}
```

And the actor, with another router injected

```
class JobActor @Inject() (@Named("b-router")bRouter: ActorRef)  extends Actor {
  def this() = {
    this(null)
  }
  override def receive = {
    case SayHello(name: String) => {
      println(bRouter)
      sender() ! "hello,"+name
    }
  }
}

object JobActor {
  def props = Props[JobActor].withDispatcher("akka.actor.default-dispatcher")
}
```

But instead of injecting the `b-router` , the constructor with no argument is invoked, so I can't simply get a `b-router` into the routee of this RoundRobinPool.

I do understand that the child actor (say `Actor[akka://application/user/job-router/$a#-22311049]`) is not directly injected by Guice, just wonder if there is a simplified manner to do this.

Since the actual routee `job-router/$a#-22311049` is a child of RoundRobinPool, is it the best practice that I implement the RoundRobinPool to inject and pass it down to the routee?

#### Update:

This would do the job for injecting an actor:

```
context.actorSelection("akka://application/user/b-router")
```

Hou about other service injected by Guice?

#### Update 2:

Temporarily solved, by injecting into another "top level" actor  (`dao-provider-actor`):

```
lazy val dao=Await.result((context.actorSelection("/user/dao-provider-actor") ? GetXDao).mapTo[XDAO],10.milliseconds)
```